# Best way to travel from Peru to Ecuador

Tags: buses, peru, south-america, ecuador

I was trying to find a way to travel from Peru to Ecuador around the beginning of March 2019.

I will be in Lima and trying to get to Ecuador, doesn't matter exactly where so it could be Guayaquil, Cuenca, Quito, or other.

The flights from Lima to Ecuador are very expensive for my budget, around US$200 or more. Going by car/bus from Lima to Ecuador is a very long journey that I would rather avoid.

I was thinking to book a flight from Lima to northern Peru (Talara or Piura, around US$50) and take a bus from there to Ecuador.

Is it a good way to pass the border on land between these two countries? I don't know how the road is there, if the waiting time at the border is long, if it is dangerous, etc.

Comment: Honestly, you'd think that Lionel Messi wouldn't worry about a $200 airplane ticket...  :D

Comment: You should make your question more specific.  Currently it is so general that it is hard to answer.  EG have a defined starting pint in Peru and a fixed destination in Ecuador.  Going overland from Talara or Piura would involve different land borders and different options.

Comment: @PeterM I cannot make it more specific because I don't have an exact plan. I'm just trying to go to Ecuadoar from Lima, that's all. Maybe it's too broad but this is all I know for the moment

Comment: @FreeMan you're right :)

Comment: The *$* or *S/* symbol is used for many different currencies, including Peruvian soles. I assume you intend USD here, but a quick [edit] to specify might head off any ambiguity for future visitors (e.g. *US$200* or *200 USD*. It is not standard to write *200 $*).

Comment: @choster I'm pretty sure it's about USD because the currency setting on rome2rio is set to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheapest way is Lima to Piura overnight bus (16hrs). Piura to Loja bus (8 & half hrs) & Loja to Quito overnight bus (12 hrs).

We wanted cheapest & needed to go quick so this is how we done it. We didn't stop off anywhere. We found the border pretty straight forward actually & total cost was about $30.

Comment: So it was a near 2 day journey from Lima to Quito, that's pretty long but if it was only 30$ I think it's very cheap. Did you booked it in advance, bought the tickets from there or how? I was just looking on rome2rio (https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Lima/Quito) and the bus options they have are no cheaper than 200$

Comment: we bought them at busbud.com but you can also get tickets from a local bus station